# how to unstuck keyboard from alt-gr?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use debian 9 (jessie) and played around with various keyboards (all the "us international with dead keys"). Now i am stuck with permanently having alt-gr added to key presses:
when I press apostrophe (key scan code 48) I get 0xfe51 (`) which I should get when AltGr 
is pressed (which is not) instead of 0x27 ('), which I should get without AltGr. When I press 
AltGr then I get 0x27 (in lieu of 0xfe51). I can use any of the US international keyboards, even the one without dead keys.

I read  [Why does US International Keyboard break Alt_R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/why-does-us-international-keyboard-break-alt-r) but cannot see how this explains the issue I observe.

The issue occurs already before I log in (i.e. I get incorrect characters in the login window.

I have seen the same effects with debian jessie and a linux mint installation
`Linux frankadmin-ThinkPad-S3-Yoga-14 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. The problem occurs the same.

What would be the perfect keyboard to produce a regular US keyboard (with no dead keys) and give with AltGr access to the international characters (accented, umlaut and similar)?

What specific information could I provide to help? 
Thank you for clarification and help!
andrew

Answer (score 0):

I hunted on the web and found one similar case in which the solution indicated that the problem was caused by an error in one of the keyboard layouts which then made AltGr stuck. I assume that I have added a keyboard with an error (from the debian site? not likely..). The problem has gone away after cleaning out all the keyboard layouts.

Now i have only 
1. English(US)
2. English(US,  alternative international)
3. English(internatinal AltGr dead keys)

Installed in debian from their site. The keyboard 2 has ' and " as dead keys to select
alternative characters, whereas 3 has no dead keys and has the international characters wtih AltGr. The names seem confusing to me; keyboard 3 is my prefered solution!

Linux london 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux